# How to filter custom attribute in model laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
//return
{
    "data": [
        {
            "tanggal_lahir": {
                "tanggal": "2000-01-29",
                "umur": 21
            }

//model
protected $appends = ['umur'];

public function getTanggalLahirAttribute($value){
    if(@$value){
        $umur = Carbon::parse($value)->diffInYears(Carbon::now());
        if(@$umur){
            return [
                'tanggal' => $value,
                'umur' => $umur
            ];
        }else{
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
```

how to query filter umur in my case?
####################################
####################################

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database does not know the `umur` attribute so you cannot filter it in the query builder.

```php
// This won't work because the umur column does not exist in the database
Model::where('umur', 'something')->get();
```

However, you can use the Collection's `where()` method to filter the results or `filter()` for more precise filtering.

```php
Model::get()
    ->where('umur', 'something');
```

```php
Model::get()
    ->filter(function ($model) {
        return preg_match(pattern, $model->umur);
    });
```